# Random Ad pop ups in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, malware

Whenever I'm browsing the web I get these random pop up ads.

I really can't understand why, I have ad-block plus. Is it possible that I've been infected with malware or ad-ware? How can I put an end to the random popups?

Facts that may be important:

- I use Google Chrome
- I only have ad-block installed

Answer (score 1):

1. Manually check your Chrome extensions for any suspicious or unknown add-on. If there are any, do remove it.
2. You'd better see into the pop-ups and check whether they have anything in common like showing 'ads by blabla'. Then search your system for its file folders to clear. Show all folders at first.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though AdBlock plus
is injecting advertising into its
userbase. I've had several new
tabs opened without my consent.

There are various clones of adblock
on the chrome extension searcher to
my knowledge

Fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop
Fresh install of Google Chrome

- 1 extension ( AdBlock )

AdBlock is blocking competition... for their own ads!?!?!??

https://www.theverge.com/2016/9/13/12890050/adblock-plus-now-sells-ads
https://www.engadget.com/2016/09/13/adblock-plus-acceptable-ads-platform/

.. advertising monopoly built on top of the guise that it is blocking "bad" adverts?